# What is the correct where clause when values in a map of values are strings?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

In the [Map of Values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays#solution_a_map_of_values) examples provided in the Cloud Firestore documentation, the two data types used as values are `booleans` and numbers in the form of `UNIX` timestamps.

I want to have the values be strings so that I can order the names of the items when I am displaying the results.

How do I set up the “where”, so I get the result set I’m seeking?

If my collection is rinks referenced by rinksRef and my Map of Values in a rink document is of the following form :

hockey_leagues :

```
{NHL: “Bell MTS Place”,
 AHL: “Bell MTS Place”}
```

I’m trying to select the rinks where the NHL plays.

My query in the JavaScript Admin SDK is currently :

```
var query = rinksRef.where('hockey_leagues.NHL', '>',0).limit(100).orderBy("hockey_leagues.NHL").get()
```

What should the comparison operator and value be, in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to select the entities in a Map of Values where the values are strings, the operator to use is greater than ( > ) and the value can be an empty string ( ‘’ ).

So the correct line of code is:

```
var query = rinksRef.where(‘hockey_leagues.NHL’, ‘>’, ‘’).limit(100).orderBy(‘hockey_leagues.NHL).get();
```